# Tests do not run with Gradle-Appengine-Plugin / Android Studio 3.0 / Gradle 4.1

Tags: android-studio, google-app-engine, gradle

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 / Gradle 4.1, I find that I can no longer run jUnit tests for an Appengine module in Android Studio.  The gradle console reports:

`Class not found: "com.example.test.PackageName"Empty test suite.`

The class file is generated when I run from Android studio, and I can still run the tests from the command line.

My suspicion is that the problem is related to this log line that I see when running from the command line:

`setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.`

There is [ticket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/issues/290) for this issue in the `gradle-appengine-plugin` project on GitHub, but it is not connected to Android Studio.

I'm assuming that there is a bug here somewhere, but maybe someone has a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There are the next information on the https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/:

"Creating App Engine-based cloud backends is not supported in Android Studio 3.0; however, your existing projects with cloud backends will continue to work in Android Studio."

My appengine backend does not work. I'm trying to migrate to the free Community version of IntelliJ Idea as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/migrate

Answer (score 0):

It's only a partial solution, but commenting out these lines in the build.gradle file of the appengine module works for me:

in the general scope:

```
apply plugin: 'appengine'
```

and all of the `appengine` scope:

```
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = false
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = false
    }
}
```

in the `dependencies` scope:

```
appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:${rootProject.ext.appengineSdkVersion}"
```

I comment out the lines when I'm testing the code locally, and uncomment them before deploying.

- keep in mind you might have a slightly different appengine configuration in the build.gradle file.